# How to ship and run spark-submit with virtualenv

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, virtualenv

am trying to submit spark job on standalone cluster, I've zipped the virtualenv as `venv.zip` and I submit the job as shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
PYSPARK_PYTHON=./venv/bin/python \
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=./venv/bin/python 
spark-submit \
--jars ojdbc6.jar \
--master spark://HOST:7077 \
--archives venv.zip#venv \
job.py
```

but I keep getting that modules are not found even though it exists in the venv and it runs fine in local mode.

I also tried to log into worker node and try run the venv, **after activating the virtualenv manually** , the modules can be found, it seems the scripts are using system-wide python, how can I fix this ?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Ryan, yes, updated

Comment: Thanks for the update! Was hoping to achieve this setup for local cluster running unit tests on CI pipeline. Are you doing anything similar?

Comment: as I mentioned, the concept is the same, all nodes need to have access to the same "path", either it's a shared path or replicated path on each node

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I could do it with the below snippet. Basically, I zipped the venv content and put the venv in `HDFS` (if you don't have HDFS or any shared accessible location by the nodes). If you don't have, then I think you can clone the virtual environment on all nodes under same path

```
#!/bin/sh
PYSPARK_PYTHON=./venv/bin/python \
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=./venv/bin/python \
spark-submit \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./venv/bin/python \
--conf spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./venv/bin/python \
--conf spark.yarn.dist.archives=hdfs:///user/sw/python-envs/venv.zip#venv \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs \
--conf spark.executorEnv.HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--py-files p1.py,p2.py \
main.py
```